# JavaScript Node Segmentation fault

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working on a Windows 11 Laptop and Ubuntu 22LTS desktop PC. Only on PC the program suddenly interrupts. After some research I found out it's running in an 'Segmentation fault' - error, when loading some data from a postgres DB and creating an Object with it. The error occurs as soon as the constructor is called.

```
import SegFaultHandler from 'segfault-handler'

SegFaultHandler.registerHandler("crash.log")

export async function _init(containerName) {
    let sqlQueries = {
        loadItemData: {
            syntax: 'select * from containercontent where itemname = $1',
            variables: [containerName],
        },
    };
    let containerData = await dbHandler
        .sqlQuery(sqlQueries.loadItemData.syntax, sqlQueries.loadItemData.variables)
        .then((res) => res.rows[0]);
    let Container = new Container();

    return Container;
}
export class Container extends MarketObject {
    constructor() {...} // <-- the error occurs
```

I have already reinstalled vsCode, node, npm and all dependencies. I also googled and followed some instructions. One of them was to install the 'segfault-handler'. Now I have a log, but I don't understand it:

```
PID 35548 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x7c
/home/nox/mega/GitHub/JavaScript/market/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x3340)[0x7f72e3f1d340]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f72e3842520]
node(_ZNK2v88internal13ScopeIterator15VisitLocalScopeERKSt8functionIFbNS0_6HandleINS0_6StringEEENS3_INS0_6ObjectEEENS1_9ScopeTypeEEENS1_4ModeES8_+0x14d)[0xe4cf1d]
node(_ZN2v88internal13ScopeIterator11ScopeObjectENS1_4ModeE+0x67)[0xe4d667]
node(_ZN2v88internal13DebugEvaluate14ContextBuilderC1EPNS0_7IsolateEPNS0_15JavaScriptFrameEi+0xf0)[0xe3f570]
node(_ZN2v88internal13DebugEvaluate5LocalEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_12StackFrameIdEiNS0_6HandleINS0_6StringEEEb+0x82)[0xe3f7e2]
node(_ZN2v88internal23DebugStackTraceIterator8EvaluateENS_5LocalINS_6StringEEEb+0x60)[0xe4eab0]
node(_ZN12v8_inspector19V8DebuggerAgentImpl19evaluateOnCallFrameERKNS_8String16ES3_N8v8_crdtp6detail10ValueMaybeIS1_EENS6_IbEES8_S8_S8_S8_NS6_IdEEPSt10unique_ptrINS_8protocol7Runtime12RemoteObjectESt14default_deleteISD_EEPNS5_8PtrMaybeINSC_16ExceptionDetailsEEE+0x286)[0x13ac266]
node(_ZN12v8_inspector8protocol8Debugger20DomainDispatcherImpl19evaluateOnCallFrameERKN8v8_crdtp12DispatchableE+0x30f)[0x1633fff]
node(_ZN8v8_crdtp14UberDispatcher14DispatchResult3RunEv+0x1b)[0x13eda6b]
node(_ZN12v8_inspector22V8InspectorSessionImpl23dispatchProtocolMessageENS_10StringViewE+0x1a0)[0x13b9880]
node[0xc8e1fa]
node[0xca7eb1]
node[0xca63ae]
node[0xca66fe]
node[0xca6b1a]
node(_ZN4node11Environment21RunAndClearInterruptsEv+0x148)[0xb0a378]
node(_ZN4node9inspector19NodeInspectorClient21runMessageLoopOnPauseEi+0x8c)[0xc8ed2c]
node(_ZN12v8_inspector10V8Debugger18handleProgramBreakEN2v85LocalINS1_7ContextEEENS2_INS1_5ValueEEERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEENS1_4base7EnumSetINS1_5debug11BreakReasonEiEENSE_13ExceptionTypeEb+0x2e5)[0x1392bb5]
node(_ZN12v8_inspector10V8Debugger21BreakProgramRequestedEN2v85LocalINS1_7ContextEEERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEENS1_4base7EnumSetINS1_5debug11BreakReasonEiEE+0x1a)[0x1392c0a]
node(_ZN2v88internal5Debug12OnDebugBreakENS0_6HandleINS0_10FixedArrayEEENS0_10StepActionENS_4base7EnumSetINS_5debug11BreakReasonEiEE+0x1b2)[0xe5a4a2]
node(_ZN2v88internal5Debug5BreakEPNS0_15JavaScriptFrameENS0_6HandleINS0_10JSFunctionEEE+0x220)[0xe5a6d0]
node(_ZN2v88internal28Runtime_DebugBreakOnBytecodeEiPmPNS0_7IsolateE+0x246)[0x12cf6a6]
node[0x1703c39]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Is anybody able to read some meaningful hint out of it?

---

New Info:

Seems like the following function after the constructor is causing the error:

```
export class Container extends MarketObject {
    constructor() {...} // <-- the error occurs
    
    saveDBData = async function () { //<--this function causes the error
        await dbHandler.sqlQuery(this.sqlQueries.saveItemData.syntax, 
           this.sqlQueries.saveItemData.variables);
     }
...
};
```

Just for your notice, the dbHandler.js looks like this, but I realy don't think its faulty. I'm using this all over the program:

```
import pg from 'pg';
import ini from 'ini';
import fs from 'fs';
import { error } from 'console';

async function getConnection() {
    try {
        let dbaccess = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./tools/database/db.ini', 'utf-8'));
        let client = new pg.Client(dbaccess['postgresql_loginData']);
        return client;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.error(error.message);
    }
}

export async function sqlQuery(syntax, values) {
    try {
        let client = await getConnection();
        await client.connect();
        let res = await client.query(syntax, values);

        await client.end();

        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.stack);
    }
}
```

Comment: On a platform like Node, a SIGSEGV nearly always means a bug in the runtime. It's probably triggered by something in your code (well, obviously) but it's not supposed to fail that way.

Comment: What Node version is it?

Comment: It's node version 18.17.0

Comment: [This Node bug report might be of interest.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47416) It suggests that some `.so.node` module you're using (?) may be at fault.

Comment: I already executed 'npm rebuild'. I also just deleted the node_modules directory ... still the same error

Comment: ?? Deleting `node_modules` *should* break everything; that's where all your installed packages are. The bug report is about looking for `.so.node` files under `node_modules`.

Comment: I turned back to an older version and everything works fine.  It appears that some code  in the class (which is loaded (?) but not executed yet) after the constructor, is causing the error.

Comment: Seems like the following function inside the class is causing the error:  ```  saveDBData = async function () {
  await dbHandler.sqlQuery(this.sqlQueries.saveItemData.syntax, this.sqlQueries.saveItemData.variables);
 }; ```

Comment: I also edited the question

Comment: Probably something you're doing (not doing wrong, just doing) there is causing a call into a native code module (that is, compiled C or C++) and the native code in the module has a bug. Native modules are common for database connector packages.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's probably not something you can solve without building the offending package yourself and debugging it. Check for other versions of packages etc with `npm outdated`

Comment: Any ideas why it happens on Ubuntu, but not on Windows? .. just for interest

Comment: Well the native shared libraries would be different for Windows vs. for Linux.